# Should I use "the" in this sentence?

Tags: articles

Would you say:

I have a good knowledge of Japanese language and culture

or

I have a good knowledge of *the* Japanese language and culture

Which one sounds better to you?

Answer (score 1):

Both sound okay, but I would go with the sentence not using "the."

Be as concise as can be without losing understanding!

Hope this helps!